# How do you create a List<T> from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a DAL method that returns an IEnumerable. I want a list of business objects, `List<Person>`. How do I build the list from the ienumerable return type ? When I inspect the return value in visual studio I see all the properties. i Just need to make the list.

thanks!

Comment: `When I inspect the return value in visual studio I see all the properties.`  Then it's not an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4):

If the `IEnumerable` contains objects of a known type `T`, you can simply "convert" it to an `IEnumerable<T>` and then get a list using the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method:

```
IEnumerable foo; // obviously this needs to have a "real" value
var list = foo.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Enumerable<T>.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<T> source = // get data from some source;
List<T> list = source.ToList();
```

Alternatively, there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) of `List<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<T> source = // get data from source;
List<T> list = new List<T>(source);
```

or

```
List<T> list = new List<T>(// get data from source);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new List<Person>(MyMethod())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ToList() when getting the results. Like this:

```
List<Person> lstPerson = DAL.GetPersonList().ToList();
```